# jQuery animation on negative margin - unexpected results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

### Project Outline

I am building a web page with a slide out menu, which works as expected and the display stays the way I expect it would during the animations to slide the menu in/out.

### This is working correctly on the following browsers;

#### Windows

Internet Explorer (11.0.9600.17239)
Firefox (32.0)
Opera (17.12)
Chrome (38.0.2125.44 beta-m)

#### Mac

Opera (12.15)
FireFox (32.0)
Chrome (36.0.1985.125)
Safari (6.0.5)

#### iOS

Chrome (37.0.2062.52)
Safari (Iphone 5s - can't find version number)

### Problem Browser

The problem seems to only be with Safari on windows (5.1.7);

### The Issue

When you click to slide out the menu, it appears to reload and slide in from the right, when it is off-page to the left, so I'd assume it should come in from the left like every other browser I've tried!

When the menu is out and you press for it to slide back in, it seems to slide off to the left and then slide back out from the right and all the way off the left again.

### Related jsFiddle link and code

(Link at the end of post)

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Set menu_out var, for clicks to activate slideIn/Out
    var menu_out = false;
    
    // Works if menu is in OR out;
    $(".top_button").click(function () {
        menu_move();
    });
    $('#menu a').click(function () {
        menu_move();
    });
    // Only work if menu if out;
    $('#content').click(function () {
        if (menu_out == true) {
            menu_move();
        }
    });
    function menu_move() {
        if (menu_out) {
            $('#menu').animate({
                'margin-left': "-71%"
            }, 300, function () {
                menu_out = false;
            });
        } 
        else {
            $('#menu').animate({
                'margin-left': "0"
            }, 300, function () {
                menu_out = true;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

#### CSS

```
* {
    font-family:"Helvetica Neu", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}
html, body {
    background: #c3c3c3;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 0;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#menu {
    background: #000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    margin-left: -71%;
    float: left;
}
.menu_item {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #333;
    background: #222222;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}
.menu_item a {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 12px 0 0 15px;
}
.menu_head {
    height: 47px;
}
.menu_head h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 14px 0 15px 10px;
    margin: 0;
    background: #000;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #333;
}
#content {
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.top_button {
    border: none;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    left: 18px;
}
.button_strips {
    width: 21px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 3px 5px;
    background: white;
}
.top {
    height: 46px;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #333;
    position: relative;
}
.display {
    text-align: right;
    white-space: nowrap
}
p {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="menu">
        <div class="menu_head"><h1>MENU</h1></div>
        <div class="menu_item"><a href="#">Link 1</a></div>
        <div class="menu_item"><a href="#">Link 2</a></div>
        <div class="menu_item"><a href="#">Link 3</a></div>
        <div class="menu_item"><a href="#">Link 4</a></div>
        <div class="menu_item"><a href="#">Link 5</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="top"> <a class="top_button">
            <div class="button_strips"></div>
            <div class="button_strips"></div>
            <div class="button_strips"></div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="display">
            <!-- Add text when needed /-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L7zs39dj/

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use preventDefault when using function event with link:

```
$('#menu a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu_move();
    });
```

Comment: Oops, I stripped out what I didn't need for display purposes - accidentally deleted that part from the jQuery before adding to the fiddle - good spot though :)